# OpenCL parametization of arguments when using OpenCV UMat as input

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I've been looking at source code of [simple opencl example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/tapi/opencl_custom_kernel.cpp) to better understand how to write opencv code.

It seems that [kernel definition](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/tapi/opencl_custom_kernel.cpp#L13-L16) has the argument list consisiting of 9 arguments:

```
"__kernel void magnutude_filter_8u(\n"
"       __global const uchar* src, int src_step, int src_offset,\n"
"       __global uchar* dst, int dst_step, int dst_offset, int dst_rows, int dst_cols,\n"
"       float scale)\n"
```

but it is [called](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/tapi/opencl_custom_kernel.cpp#L135-L140) only with 3 arguments:

```
bool executionResult = k
     .args(
            cv::ocl::KernelArg::ReadOnlyNoSize(src), // size is not used (similar to 'dst' size)
            cv::ocl::KernelArg::WriteOnly(result),
            (float)2.0
        )
```

This happens as well in other code, for example the canny [.cl](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/opencl/canny.cl#L119-L122) and [.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/canny.cpp#L234-L236) implementations.

I'm wondering what is so special about the UMat structure that allows this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you browsed the opencv code a bit more you would have found that the
[ReadOnlyNosize](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/42459cad02e83fe3ade559f1b8c43923c38146ed/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/ocl.hpp#L370) and [WriteOnly](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/42459cad02e83fe3ade559f1b8c43923c38146ed/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/ocl.hpp#L368) functions return a kernelArg which seems to be 4 values packed into a struct, from these 3 are "used" by your kernel, for each KernelArg 2 values are assigned by default, in this case these match to, src_step, src_offset, dst_step and dst_offset, on the other hand the dst_rows and dst_cols parameters are deduced from the dst UMat size (see again the set() call), which are all the needed arguments for the OpenCL function call.

Now args(...) calls set(int index, T type) for each argument, in the case of a KernelArg it would be

```
set(int i, const KernelArg &arg);
```

Which does this [set call](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/558b17dede2816fded97aa7d3f18396ed3ce6956/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp#L2933), meaning it unpacks (uses the members of) the KernelArg struct.
And if you wonder where they're assigned to the kernel is on the many

```
clSetKernelArg(..)
```

calls inside the function

Comment: this still doesn't make sense because, the ReadOnlyNoSize call matches only 3 args (__global const uchar* src, int src_step, int src_offset) and WriteOnly call matches 5 args (__global uchar* dst, int dst_step, int dst_offset, int dst_rows, int dst_cols)

Comment: @zcaudate I've expanded my answer.

Comment: @zcaudate I would say you're going to low level in the opencv api, you don't need to know this unless you want to contribute to opencv or something, the only thing you need to know is when to use the according step values in your custom kernel, they default to 1 in this case becasuse of KernelArg. In case you need different stride steps you can do WriteOnly(Mat, stride, stride) etc. KernelArg is overloaded up to 16 values! (see ocl.hpp)